# Why won't this work processing?

Tags: javascript, processing

I have tried this countless times. According to the processing.js website all that is needed to run a sketch in the browser is the following html code:

```
<script src="processing-1.4.1.min.js"></script>

<canvas data-processing-sources="example.pde"></canvas>
```

I tested the code in the processing.js compiler by starting the server and the code works fine but here it is:

```
void setup()
{
  size(200,200);
}

boolean pressed=false;

void draw()
{
  if (pressed)
    background(255);
  else
    background(0);  
}

void mousePressed()
{
  pressed=true;
}

void mouseReleased()
{
  pressed=false;
}
```

I don't know if there is a directory problem or what but I saved a .txt file as an  example.html containing the html code at the top of this query. This html file was saved in the same directory as the example.pde file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `processing-1.4.1.min.js` in the same folder too?

Comment: When you open file in browser can you open a debugger to check js file is getting loaded? or it says some Processing or some function is not defined?

Comment: Yes the processing-1.4.1.min.js was in the same folder. For the canvas tag does a directory to find the example.pde need to be specified?

Comment: All of the code works fine I just get a white screen when I open the html file where the html code was saved.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be running into a same-origin policy issue. I was able to run your sketch through a local webserver but when I tried to just open the HTML file with Chrome I got this (right click page > Inspect element > Console tab):

> Uncaught Processing.js: Unable to load pjs sketch files: example.pde
>   ==> XMLHttpRequest failure, possibly due to a same-origin policy violation. You can try loading this page in another browser, or load
>   it from http:// localhost using a local webserver. See the
>   Processing.js README for a more detailed explanation of this problem
>   and solutions.

You can find the Processing.js README file [here](https://github.com/jeresig/processing-js/blob/master/README.md#loading-processingjs-sketches-locally) but basically you can either run a local webserver, or try opening your HTML file in another browser (Firefox maybe), or disable same-origin policy checking in your browser (chrome --disable-web-security, for example). Note though that this last option is unsafe, as explained in the README file linked above.

Let me know if this solution works for you.